# Sql Using Group by Functions

Tags: sql

This is my data table. I need to Get Each and every `Employee` `BasicSalary`, `Code`, `Travel`, `Phone`, `ESI.PF`

Can anyone help with this?

```
year | month | EmpID | Component | Amount | Remarks
2013 | 3     | 2     | Basicsal  | 15000  | dsf
2013 | 3     | 2     | CODE      | 2      | dsf
2013 | 3     | 2     | Travel    | 0      | dsf
2013 | 3     | 2     | Phone     | 1500   | dsf
2013 | 3     | 2     | Internet  | 500    | dsf
2013 | 3     | 2     | Bus Allo  | 0      | dsf
2013 | 3     | 2     | BF        | 0      | dsf
2013 | 3     | 2     | ESI       | 0      | dsf
2013 | 3     | 2     | Medic     | -500   | dsf
2013 | 3     | 2     | Cress     | 101752 | af
2013 | 3     | 2     | Net       | 101552 | asf
etc. | ..    | ..    | ...       | ....   | ...
```

But I need output like this

```
Year | Month | EmpID | Basicsalary | CODE | Travel | Phone | cress  | net 
2013 | 3     | 2     | 15000       | 2    | 0      | 1500  | 101752 | 101552
```

Comment: What RDBMS you are using??

Comment: The answer to his is very different for Oracle vs MySQL, search for "pivot" for answers

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't specify what RDBMS you are using, then try this:

```
SELECT 
  year,
  month,
  EmpID,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Component = 'Basicsalary' THEN Amount END) AS Basicsalary,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Component = 'Code'        THEN Amount END) AS Code,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Component = 'Travel'      THEN Amount END) AS Travel,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Component = 'Phone'       THEN Amount END) AS Phone,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Component = 'Chress'      THEN Amount END) AS Chress,
  MAX(CASE WHEN Component = 'net'         THEN Amount END) AS net,
FROM tablename
GROUP BY year, 
         month,
         EmpId;
```

Comment: @PeterWooster This should work fine for all RDBMS, at least Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server. If you are using SQL Server or Oracle you can use the `PIVOT` table operator instead, to do the same.

Comment: +1 Thanks, it looked like ANSI SQL to me, but there are a lot of other solutions that are Db specific.  And you had asked the same question of the OP.

Comment: @PeterWooster Yes, since the OP didn't specify what RDBMS, I posted a solution that should work regardless what RDBMS he is using.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server or Oracle as your database, then you can apply the `PIVOT` function to get the result.

Your code will be similar to the following:

```
select year, 
  month, 
  empid,
  Basicsal, 
  Code, 
  Travel, 
  Phone, 
  Cress, 
  Net
from
(
  select year, month, empid, component, amount
  from yourtable
) src
pivot
(
  max(amount)
  for component in (Basicsal, Code, Travel, Phone, Cress, Net)
) piv
```